# How to limit one role per user?

Tags: 7, users

How do I limit one role per user?

I want to see a select form field, instead of checkboxes for roles when I go to /user/#/edit.
So far I tried overwriting the `$form['account']['roles']` in template.php, replace the checkboxes with a select dropdown, but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working! The following will change the registration and profile forms to output role selection as a select form field.

Include the following in the module:

```
//replace roles checkboxes in registration form with select field
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['account']['roles']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['account']['roles']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}

//replace roles checkboxes in profile form with select field
function MYMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['account']['roles']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['account']['roles']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}

//hack for registration & profile forms, attaches the authenticated role
function MODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($edit['roles'])) {
    is_array($edit['roles']) ? '' : $edit['roles'] = array ( $edit['roles'] => $edit['roles'], 2 => '1' );
    $edit['roles'] = array_filter($edit['roles']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will be best using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

You can edit the registration form & user edit form and change the type in a custom module.

```
function register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form_id= 'user_register_form') {
    $form['user-register-form']['roles'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios'
      // …
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: $form['user-register-form'] doesn't exist.

Comment: this is about as close as I can get: function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { if ( $form_id == 'user_register_form') { $form['account']['roles']['#type'] = 'select'; } } but it gives me Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in user_user_presave() (line 1261 of /home/servername/public_html/drupal/modules/user/user.module).

Comment: Yea, sorry I was just on way to a meeting so didnt have time to check it over. Looks like you on the right track now though :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a module [Single User Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_user_role) to assign single role to per user. This module is also compatible with role delegation module.